# Rails: Why is my .each loop is being skipped?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I am getting new messages one at a time from an API. Each time I get a new message, I want to save the sender's name in my Contact model (where each contact belongs_to :user, and has attributes email, senderRealname, and importancePoints). With each message, before I save the sender as a new Contact, I want to check through the current user's contacts to see if the sender is already in the contact list, so that I don't save any duplicate Contacts. 


For some reason, my loop to check if the contact already exists is being skipped, so every message's sender is saved as a new contact, regardless of whether or not it will be a duplicate contact.


Here is the code from my users_controller:

```
response.each do |m|
  messageId = m['message_id']
  body1 = m['bodies'][0]['content']
  senderName = m['addresses']['from'][0]['email']
  senderActualName = m['addresses']['from'][0]['name']
  recieveTime = m['sent_at']
  subjectText = m['subject']
  isRead = m['flags']['seen']
  hasReplied = m['flags']['answered']
  importanceLevel = 0
  @contact_already_exists = 0
  @message_sender = senderName
  puts 'RIGHT BEFORE CONTACTS'

  @user.contacts.each do |c|
    if c.email.to_s == @message_sender.to_s
      importanceLevel = c.importancePoints
      @contact_already_exists = 1
      puts 'contact exists'
    else
      puts 'contact does not exist'
    end
  end

  if @contact_already_exists == 1
    puts 'No new contact'
  elsif @contact_already_exists == 0
    @newContact = Contact.new(email: senderName, realName: senderActualName, importancePoints: 0)
    @newContact.user = current_user
    @newContact.save
    puts 'new contact saved'
  end
end
```

--then I do other stuff with the message that is working fine--

For each message, the "RIGHT BEFORE CONTACTS" text is printed, then the "new contact saved" text is printed. It seems like the entire loop that checks if a contact exists is skipped, so @contact_already_exists can never be set to 1. Sorry about the sloppy variable names, still getting used to conventions!

Comment: Is there any reason you are not just using a rails validator for something like this? Can you verify that `@user.contacts` actually has records?

Comment: `@message_sender = senderName` is senderName getting set properly, containg just an email address? If there are any discrepancies, it would throw off the loop.

Comment: Can you show the `@user.contacts` output

Comment: Before the first message comes in, user.contacts is nil. But, after all the messages have come through (when response.each is completed), user.contacts is exactly the same size as user.messages, and full of duplicate contacts. It is saving the sender for each message as a new contact. I would think that it would skip the .each loop for the first message, and then use it for each message after that, because the first message's sender is saved. Unless newContact.save just adds to some kind of local array, and doesn't really save until response.each is completed?

Comment: Skipped all the "@" symbols in that comment because stackoverflow thought I was trying to reply to a bunch of users btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I just read your long comment.

Yes, `@user` is set outside the outer loop, and therefore `@user.contacts` will not be refreshed/reloaded from the database on iterations of this loop.

You can do two things to solve this, either reload your `@user` on each iteration of your loop: `@user.reload` to ensure that the `contacts` is reloaded from the DB, or change the way you build new `Contact`s to use the association, so your `elsif` becomes:

```
elsif @contact_already_exists == 0
  @user.contacts.create(email: senderName, realName: senderActualName, importancePoints: 0)
  puts "new contact saved"
```

Although my original answer was off the mark, it **is** still important to check the return of that `create` (or `save`) or change it to the `!` alternative so an exception is raised.